# Grails Inventory Desgin

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have these domain class:

```
class Product {

Manufacture manufacture
Model model
Category category
int price
String productCondition
String productDescription
}

class Manufacture {

String manufactureName

static hasMany = [products:Product, models:Model]
}

class Model {

Manufacture manufacture
String modelName

static hasMany = [products:Product]
}

class Category {

String categoryName
static hasMany = [products:Product];
}
```

I am wondering if I need a Manufacture class, Model class, and Category class or if I can just use a String manufacture, etc..  Is there any advantage to having those additional domain classes than just having String manufacture, etc when it comes to searching? Say I want all products that are manufactured by Ford, or all products that are category car. I am confused on when I should make a domain class vs just using a field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice between one solution or the other one depends on how you plan to query the application and adapt it to future changes.

You could use only a `Product` domain class and with the appropriate database indexes on `manufacture`, `model` and `category` String fields the queries would go fast. But with this approach you can not evolve easily your domain to add new fields to manufacture, model and category.

I always prefer the domain class solution because I don't know how the application is going to evolve.

And intermediate solution can be use [embedded](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#gormComposition) domain classes.